# Why is the width of gate the length of barrier?

Tags: digital-logic, semiconductors

In MOS capacitor, it is often said that width of gate is the length of barrier that blocks the flow from source to drain. Why is it called like that? I am getting mixed up in diagrams, and can someone clarify these? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post these diagrams that get you mixed up?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely provide more informations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a vastly simplified description, but basically, when a MOSFET transistor is created on the surface of an integrated circuit, first an area of diffusion is created that will carry the current between the source and the drain.

[image: drawing of MOSFET]

Next, an insulating layer of oxide is created over the entire chip. Holes are created in this layer for the source and drain contacts.

Finally, a patterned layer of metal is created on top of the oxide layer to form the source, gate and drain terminals of the transistor. The source and drain metallization is in direct contact with the channel created in the first step, while the gate metallization is insulated from the center of the channel by the oxide layer.

The active part of the transistor channel — the part that forms a barrier when the transistor is "off", or conducts when the transistor is "on" — is the area formed by the intersection of the diffusion in the first step and the gate metal in the last step. The electrons (in an N-channel device) flow from source to drain. The **length** of this channel (from the electrons' point of view) is the same as the **width** of the gate "line" that was drawn in the metal layer. The width of the channel is the same as the width of the original diffusion.

One of the fundamental limitations of any given IC "process" is how narrow the gate lines in the metal layer can be. In fact, this parameter is so important that this measurement is often the "name" of the process. When you read about the latest CPU being done in, say, a "32 nm process", this means that the minimum gate width (channel length) in this process is 32 nanometers.